# `parsel` is no longer supported. Use at your own risk for ruby 2.6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having `parsel is no longer supported. Use at your own risk` issue while upgrade rails' application on the latest version, this is run time dependency for the access-token gem.

```
`parsel` is no longer supported. Use at your own risk.
```

Called from /home/sunflower/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@formyula_er_plus/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, need to specify `gem 'parsel', '~>0.3.0'` in Gemfile, because latest version of rails is compatible with parsel 0.3.0.
`